# Unit testing bluebird promise bind function

Tags: unit-testing, bluebird, sinon, sinon-chai

I have the following function that uses `bind` to bind a context to the `then` chains. When i try and test it, it throws

```
  TypeError: redisClient.hgetallAsync(...).bind is not a function


myFunc() {
    let self = this;

    return redisClient.hgetallAsync('abcde')
      .bind({ api: self })
      .then(doStuff)
      .catch(err => {
        // error
      });
  }
```

Test

```
let redisClient = { hgetallAsync: sinon.stub() };

describe('myFunc', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      redisCLient.hgetallAsync.resolves('content!');
    });

    it('should do stuff', () => {
      return myFunc()
        .should.eventually.be.rejectedWith('Internal Server Error')
        .and.be.an.instanceOf(Error)
        .and.have.property('statusCode', 500);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `hgetallAsync` stub is returning a plain JS Promise rather than a `Bluebird` promise.

To use a `Bluebird` promise, you need to tell `Sinon` to do so using `.usingPromise()`.

```
let redisClient = { hgetallAsync: sinon.stub().usingPromise(bluebird.Promise) };
```

---

Documentation Link:
http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.1.2/stubs/#stubusingpromisepromiselibrary